Possible to optimize nx webpack build of multiple projects?
We have a repository containing 21 react applications, some of which have references to each other or common libraries.
These applications are being built using nx in our pipeline.
Here is the in-progress output of one build:
nx run application:build --verbose=true --progress=true
Starting type checking service...
Using 10 workers with 2048MB memory limit
69% building 1612/1621 modules 9 active ...\node_modules\@material-ui\core\esm\internal\svg-icons\MoreHoriz.js     

It then finishes with this:
<w> [webpack.Progress] 46443ms building
<i> [webpack.Progress] 34ms finish module graph
<i> [webpack.Progress] 52ms chunk graph
<i> [webpack.Progress] 29ms advanced chunk optimization
<i> [webpack.Progress] 17ms before module ids
<i> [webpack.Progress] 14ms module id optimization
<i> [webpack.Progress] 70ms hashing
<i> [webpack.Progress] 160ms chunk assets processing
<i> [webpack.Progress] 18ms additional asset processing
<w> [webpack.Progress] 1410ms after chunk asset optimization
<i> [webpack.Progress] 320ms emitting
Hash: 0a194d2e1887eea09834
Version: webpack 4.42.0
Built at: 13.06.2024 11:14:44
           Asset       Size     Chunks                          Chunk Names
 assets/.gitkeep    0 bytes             [emitted]
      index.html  624 bytes             [emitted]
         main.js   2.08 MiB       main  [emitted]        [big]  main
     main.js.map   2.25 MiB       main  [emitted] [dev]         main
    polyfills.js    598 KiB  polyfills  [emitted]        [big]  polyfills
polyfills.js.map    441 KiB  polyfills  [emitted] [dev]         polyfills
  primeicons.eot   56.2 KiB             [emitted]
  primeicons.svg    229 KiB             [emitted]
  primeicons.ttf     56 KiB             [emitted]
 primeicons.woff   56.1 KiB             [emitted]
      runtime.js   6.15 KiB    runtime  [emitted]               runtime
  runtime.js.map   6.13 KiB    runtime  [emitted] [dev]         runtime
       styles.js   42.7 MiB     styles  [emitted]        [big]  styles
   styles.js.map   42.8 MiB     styles  [emitted] [dev]         styles
       vendor.js    9.6 MiB     vendor  [emitted]        [big]  vendor
Entrypoint main [big] = runtime.js runtime.js.map vendor.js main.js main.js.map
Entrypoint polyfills [big] = runtime.js runtime.js.map polyfills.js polyfills.js.map
Entrypoint styles [big] = runtime.js runtime.js.map styles.js styles.js.map

My concern is that it's building everything in node_modules for every application, which means it takes about 20 minutes to build all the applications.
Is it possible to configure it so that the built modules are reused for all applications being built? They all share the same package.json.
Is there anything else we can do to speed up the build process?
